# How to save these files as a single document/File

Tags: python, reportlab

Is it possible to have these many files saved into one document, page by page

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'STREAM':['EAGLE','HAWK','HAWK','HAWK','EAGLE','HAWK','EAGLE'],'MAT':['A','D','F','D','C','C','E'],'KIS':['B','D','E','D','A','C','D'],'GEO':['B','C','E','E','F','A','B']})

dfa.to_csv('results.csv',index=False)

students_data = csv.reader(open("results.csv", 'r'))

for row in students_data:
    STREAM = row[0]
    MAT = row[1]
    GEO = row[2]
    KIS = row[3]

    c = canvas.Canvas(MAT +".pdf")
    c.drawString(60, 700, "STREAM:  " + STREAM)
    c.drawString(60, 600, "MAT:  " + MAT)
    c.drawString(60, 500, "KIS:  " + KIS)
    c.drawString(60, 400, "GEO:  " + GEO)
    c.save()
```

What this code does is save each file separately which is a bit heavy to deal with.
Anyone with an idea to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it like this:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'STREAM':['EAGLE','HAWK','HAWK','HAWK','EAGLE','HAWK','EAGLE'],'MAT':['A','D','F','D','C','C','E'],'KIS':['B','D','E','D','A','C','D'],'GEO':['B','C','E','E','F','A','B']})

dfa.to_csv('results.csv',index=False)

students_data = csv.reader(open("results.csv", 'r'))

c = canvas.Canvas("combined.pdf")
for row in students_data:
    STREAM = row[0]
    MAT = row[1]
    GEO = row[2]
    KIS = row[3]

    c.drawString(60, 700, "STREAM:  " + STREAM)
    c.drawString(60, 600, "MAT:  " + MAT)
    c.drawString(60, 500, "KIS:  " + KIS)
    c.drawString(60, 400, "GEO:  " + GEO)
    c.showPage()

c.save()
```

Comment: Great! Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?

Comment: And the first page has contents of the headers. Do you have any idea of how to exclude these from the pdf?

Comment: Sure, just replace "for row in students_data:" with "for row in [x for x in students_data][1:]:" which skips the first value (= the headers).

Comment: Thanks again for this answer.

Comment: How a bout if I have a whole file to be saved as pdf? How would I go about it?